# determinant in terms of quadratic form evaluated at a point

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant

Say $A$ is a $n$ by $n$ positive definite matrix. Let $b$ be a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the following quantity:
$$b^TA^*b$$ 
where $A^*$ is the cofactor matrix of $A$. A simple calculation reveals that this quantity is (up to a sign) the same as
$$det\left(\begin{align}A ,& b \\b^T, &0 \end{align}\right).$$

Now is there a relationship between this quantity and the determinant of $A$? By relationship, I mean one controls the other somehow. I am asking this because I was told that there might be a formula for determinants in terms of the above quantity. But the person who told me this is not sure and he doesn't remember where he saw it.

Any sort of reference towards this direction is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: try it for $n=1$ and $n=2$

Comment: @WillJagy Do you know that such a formula exists or are you just making a general comment?

Comment: I mean that if you get something worthwhile for $n=1$ and $n=2$ you can tell us about that, then ask about what happens in larger dimension. Also, some students call matrices positive definite when not even symmetric, no idea why anyone would do that but it happens. The 2 by 2 case would clear that up.

Comment: @WillJagy $n=1$ doesn't yield anything interesting. By positive definite I meant symmetric positive definite. Personally, I don't believe there is a relationship. If one just take $b$ to be an eigenvector, then the quantity given above would just be the product of the $n-1$ remaining eigenvalues. Since determinant is the product of $n$ eigenvalues, there is no guarantee that one might be bigger than the other. It all depends on whether the last eigenvalue is bigger or smaller than 1. The person who told me this seemed very certain. So I decided to ask in case people here have seen this before.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\det \begin{bmatrix} A & b \\ b^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \det  \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -b^T A^{-1} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \det \begin{bmatrix} A & b \\ b^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \det  \left( \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -b^T A^{-1} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & b \\ b^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right)$ yields

$\det \begin{bmatrix} A & b \\ b^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} = -b^T A^{-1} b \det A  $.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the blocks in the various parts? The original had the lower right block 1 by 1, so you would have just a numeral $1$

Comment: Picky, picky... (Why don't we use 1 anyway, we use 0 rather than O for the zero matrix?)

Comment: This is unfamiliar to me, still not sure the determinant ijvolved is nonzero in arbitrary dimesnion

Comment: This is not what I asked anyway. Towards the end, if you note that $A^*=det(A)A^{-1}$ you just got what I said in my post "A simple calculation reveals" .

Comment: Got it now. News to me. Well done.

Comment: @henryforever14, sorry that you want us to read both your mind and the mind of an unnamed friend. In neither case do we have any evidence about your backgrounds.

Comment: @henryforever14: Your question is a little ambiguous, so it is a little difficult to answer. You might want to work on your etiquette skills...

Comment: @WillJagy I am not trying to offend any of you. Perhaps what I said is not so polite. I apologize for that. Also to copper.hat. I can't at two users in one comment.

Comment: @henryforever14: No problem, you didn't offend. (Just reduced me to a quivering bucket of unexpurgated rage.)

Comment: @copper.hat I sincerely apologize for that. I am deleting this post.

Comment: No don't , sorry I was just kidding. But the system wouldn't let me edit my comment.